# Using an alias to form an inner join

Tags: mysql

I have a problem which I cant figure out, and have looked on google and similar questions on here, but they are just not quite the same.

I am trying to build a MySQL Query which has two parts, the first is easy and i have done this fine, as it uses existing relationships, see...

```
SELECT

clientsites.SiteName,
clients.ClientName,
pafaddresses.PostTown,
pafaddresses.PostCode,
CONCAT("XXXXXXX", Replace(UPPER(pafaddresses.PostCode),' ','')) AS JouneyKeytemp,
clientsites.SiteType
FROM clientsites
INNER JOIN clients ON clientsites.ClientFk = clients.ClientPk
INNER JOIN pafaddresses ON clients.ActualPAF = pafaddresses.id
```

You will see from this code that an alias is generated which concats two postcodes and looks like xxxxxxxyyyyyy, this does work but for obvious reasons ive removed the actual postcodes.

What I now what to do is to bring in two fields from an unrelated table called Journeys:

```
SELECT
    JourneyKey,
    SingleDistance,
    SingleTime
FROM journeys
```

I want to bring in SingleDistance and SingleTime, where the Journey Key = Generated Alias of JourneyKeyTemp.

I have tried adding the following:

```
INNER JOIN journeys ON JouneyKeytemp = journeys.JourneyKey
```

But I just keep getting a syntax error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the expression in join predicate:

```
INNER JOIN journeys
 ON CONCAT("XXXXXXX", Replace(UPPER(pafaddresses.PostCode),' ','')) = journeys.JourneyKey
```

Or you can create a subquery:

```
select * from(

SELECT

clientsites.SiteName,
clients.ClientName,
pafaddresses.PostTown,
pafaddresses.PostCode,
CONCAT("XXXXXXX", Replace(UPPER(pafaddresses.PostCode),' ','')) AS JouneyKeytemp,
clientsites.SiteType
FROM clientsites
INNER JOIN clients ON clientsites.ClientFk = clients.ClientPk
INNER JOIN pafaddresses ON clients.ActualPAF = pafaddresses.id)t

INNER JOIN journeys ON t.JouneyKeytemp = journeys.JourneyKey
```

Comment: I swear i tried that before and it didn't work does now so thanks.  Incidentally how to i get it to do a right inner join, as there isnt always an entry on the journey table so want to display all from clientsites and only matching from journeys